# Hibernate saves empty Spring autobound ojects

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, jsf-2, integration

I'm using Spring + JSF2 + Hibernate to build a web application. Two relevant classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="people")
@Named
public class Person implements Serializable {
private int id;
private String forename;
@Inject private PhoneNumber mobile_phone;
/* Other properties */

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="mobile_phone_number_id", nullable = true)
public PhoneNumber getMobilePhone() {
  return mobile_phone;
}
/* Other getters and setters */
}

@Entity
@Table(name="phone_numbers")
@Named
public class PhoneNumber {
private Integer id;
private String code;
private String number;
/* Other stuff */
}
```

Dependency injection is handled by Spring (`@Named`, `@Inject`). Database persistence is configured through Hibernate annotations (`@OneToOne`, `@JoinColumn`). JSF form elements are bound to these classes using EL.

**My question is** how to tell hibernate no to save autobound PhoneNumber if all its fields are left blank (the user doesn't submit any values)? In other words, I want the Person object to be saved but don't want records with empty strings appear in the `phone_numbers` table.

And two bonus questions if someone knows.

1. When does Spring bind the PhoneNumber - at Person creation or when a request for a PhoneNumber comes from JSF?
2. [SOLVED] I have fields in my form which aren't marked with the `required` attribute in JSF. Obviously, if such fields are left empty, validation shouldn't be triggered. The problem is that when I configured Hibernate validator, such non-required fields are now validated even when left blank. Is there any way to skip validation for empty fields which aren't marked as `required` in JSF? I tried to set `<prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">CALLBACK</prop>` in `hibernateProperties` of `SessionFactory` bean, but this didn't help.

Comment: You stick to a bad practice example of that trio reunion. 1. You'd definitely not want to mix up model classes and backing bean classes. 2. You'd definitely want to mark fields that are not persistent as `@Transient`. Finally, if you followed the standard approach that rests upon separation of application layers you would end up with a running program.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Now here are my answers to your statements. 1. I have a JSF backing bean where Person is injected as a property. I thought that rewriting all the getters and setters in the backing bean is too complicated. Correct me if I'm mistaken. 2. I know about `@Transient` annotation, but this is not the case, is it?

Comment: You don't need to inject model (entity) object. It typically acts as a *placeholder*, or DTO, or detached entity, for the data. It's preloading is done in a `@PostConstruct` method. If a new entity is to be persisted, a new object is instantiated and populated from the view. This way you refer to it in the view via `#{bean.entity.field}`. Of course, no need for code duplication.

Comment: Regarding the usage of `@Transient` this is not the case, but you should remove all `@Inject`/`@Named` annotations and let it be a plain JPA entity instead. Initially I thought you wanted to inject something that didn't refer to the entity itself, so I proposed to use `@Transient`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! To be honest, I didn't even bother with such things as application architecture, just took a basic project with dao, service, view and model layers and began writing code. But now thanks to your comment, @skuntsel, I decided to do some research and plan more carefully. For those who are interested, there's a good resource on JPA and it's Hibernate implementation: http://blog.xebia.com/category/jpa/implementation-patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The second bonus question has the following answer: JSF treats empty fields as empty strings, so one must set

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in web.xml to interpret empty strings as null. Obviously, an empty string didn't validate well against my regex validation pattern.